# How to implement rotating rectangle around circle in libGDX Box2D?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I want to implement rotating rectangle around cicrle in such way, that circle has no rotation, and rectangle has. All object's are Box2D `Body` objects. Here is picture, what I want to have:[image]

In my case rectangle touches circle, but I think it doesn't matter.

At first I tried to do it with two `Ficture`s for same `Body`, but there was a problem with rotation: I couldn't have one ficture with rotation and another without.

I think, it should be somehow connected with joints, but I don't know what exactly `Joint` I should use. Maybe are there another solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think **DistanceJointDef**  will do the tricks

you could put the radius if the circle as the distance with a little margin if you want

you also have to reduce the friction of bodies so the rectangle can move smoothly

```
    DistanceJointDef djd = new DistanceJointDef();
    djd.bodyA = bodyRactangle;
    djd.bodyB = bodyCirlce;
    djd.length = radius + margin;
    world.createJoint(djd);
```

**bodyRactangle** is a `dynamic` body

**bodyCirlce** is a `static` body

try that for a start, hope it is helpful

Good luck !!

Comment: My circle can't be ```static``` body, because it can move. Anyway, when I implemented ```DistanceJointDef``` with two ```dynamic``` bodies I get such result: my Rectangle rotates around Circle, when I ```setLinearVelocity``` of Circle along Y-axis. And ```setAngularVelocity(0)``` doesn't help. What could be cause of it?